# ¿how to add lines in a rectangle fabricjs canvas

Tags: angular, typescript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

How can you add lines inside a rectangle?

For example, if my rectangle has a height of 90 and I want to add 2 lines, it should appear like this, adj image [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oguGBGZFrnay2SyR6S2M1EmFTtcbuiJe/view?usp=sharing)

but currently it comes out like this, adj image [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Ik228cxlZn6ugC8GY6T3OjFqe5Nf4KX/view?usp=sharing)

I have 2 functions, one that creates lines and the other that creates rectangles.
then in the function of the rectangle I invoke the line, but they do not come out like the first image

```
  addLineToRectangle(){
    console.log("activeObject",this.rect.width);
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      let line = new fabric.Line([0, 100, 90, 100], {
        left: 1,
        top: 30 * i,
        stroke: 'red'
      });
      this.canvas?.add(line);
    }
  }

    
  addRect(){
    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      this.rect = new fabric.Rect( {
        width: 90,
        height: 90,
        fill: 'transparent',
        stroke: 'blue',
        left: 1,
        top: 90 * i,
      });
      this.canvas?.add(this.rect);
      this.addLineToRectangle();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I had also seen that possibility, but if you add more line it already leaves the rectangle, how could it be so that it does not leave the rectangle, thanks. adj image [https://drive.google.com/file/d/10GWvbdJ2ct29AJ-sE5g7k_zhdUtY7GNM/view?usp=sharing]

Answer (score 0):

In FabricJS, `Line` has some interesting characteristics; you might consider switching to a `Polyline`. That said, here's a revised `addLineToRectangle` that works for me:

```
addLineToRectangle() {
  console.log("activeObject",this.rect.width);
  for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    let line = new fabric.Line([0, 0, 90, 0], {
      left: 1,
      top: 30 * i,
      stroke: 'red',
    });
    canvas.add(line);
  }
}
```

Your `top` was starting at zero, and going up from there. I bumped your loop to start with 1, and also tweaked the y component of your line.

Comment: I had also seen that possibility, but if you add more line it already leaves the rectangle, how could it be so that it does not leave the rectangle, thanks. adj image [https://drive.google.com/file/d/10GWvbdJ2ct29AJ-sE5g7k_zhdUtY7GNM/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you need to change the 30 for `top` to something computed from the number of lines. Something along the lines of `rectHeight/(numLines+1)` might do it, but this is moving away from the original question.

Comment: then I should reframe the question, query and how could I do so that the lines are generated at each rectangle that is created.